# how to get mutual TLS authentication working in Postman for gRPC

Tags: openssl, postman, grpc, mtls

I have a `gRPC` service that I can run with:

- no authentication
- server side only authentication
- mutual authentication

Using x509 openSSL certificates I generated using `openssl`.

I have verified correct operation of the server by using `grpc_cli` for all 3 modes.

Now I'm trying to use `Postman` because it has a nicer GUI, and it supports streaming RPCs in addition to the unary ones to which `grpc_cli` is restricted.

But I'm finding it a challenge to configure `Postman` to work with `mTLS`. The documentation is very clear and I've followed the steps, but my server responds with:

```
E1106 18:51:49.979164000 6136066048 ssl_transport_security.cc:1420]    Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000c0:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:PEER_DID_NOT_RETURN_A_CERTIFICATE.
```

Whenever I invoke a `gRPC` call that works just fine when the server is running with just server-side authentication. Conclusion: `postman` isn't presenting a cert with the `gRPC` invocation.

Maybe `postman` doesn't yet support `mTLS` with `gRPC`? All the examples in the documentation are for `HTTPS`.

My `postman` certificate settings are (`gRPC` settings tab):

- enable server certificate verification = true
- overwrite server name for certificate verification = the `Subject` in the server cert, the server's actually running at localhost:nnnn

and ('postman` general settings):

- CA certificates - I uploaded my `ca.crt` file which is used to sign both the client & server certs here.
- Host - set to a wildcard that matches both the client and server `Subject` fields in the certs used.
- CRT file = `/path/to/client.crt`
- KEY file = `/path/to/client.key`

Last piece of info - I get nothing in the `postman` console when invoking the `gRPC`. It's completely blank.

Thanks in advance for your help,

VS